# Coordinate Capture in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis-3, coordinates, copy

My understanding is that "Coordinate Capture" is *"built into"* QGIS 3.0, rather than being a Plugin. However, I can't find where to start it.

How do I navigate to that option and what do I need to do to have coordinate capture show as an icon?

Answer (score 9):

Hamp, Welcome to GIS StackExchange.
The "Coordinate Capture" function is one of the core 'plugins' now. Just go to 'Plugins' on the top menu & search for 'Coordinate'. Click on 'Coordinate Capture' to display the 'Coordinate Capture' toolbar.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. One of the first things I did after installing QGIS 3.0 was to try to install the plugin "coordinate capture". In the plug-in search box I submitted "coordinate capture", but the search came up with nothing.  That is when I read something about the feature being integrated into 3.0 -- lead me to look for the icon or line in a menu. Following your instructions, I again sent tothe plugin search box and found that searching for "coordinate" brings up the "coordinate capture" plugin even though searching for "coordinate capture" does not.

Comment: Glad to help Hamp. I think you've discovered an anomaly there with the search. Please mark this question as Answered if it helped.

Comment: Dumb question: How do I mark the question as being answered?

Comment: Hamp, next to my answer, you just toggle the checkmark on like discussed here https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers Thanks!